# android web browser b tag not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, android-webview

I am using the WebView in Android JellyBean.

I have style element:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    div.d1{margin-right:0.74791664in;  margin-left:0.74791664in;}
    div.d2{margin-right:0.74791664in;  margin-left:0.74791664in;max-height:10.820139in;min-height:10.820139in;}

    p.p1{text-align:justify;hyphenate:auto;font-family:David;font-size:12pt;}
    p.p2{text-align:center;hyphenate:auto;font-family:David;font-size:12pt;}
    p.p3{text-align:justify;direction:rtl;hyphenate:auto;font-family:David;font-size:8pt;}
    p.p4{padding-right:-4pt;text-align:center;direction:rtl;hyphenate:auto;keep-together.within-page:always;keep-with-next.within-page:always;font-family:David Bold Bold;font-size:36pt;}

    p.p5{text-indent:-18pt;padding-right:35pt;text-align:justify;direction:rtl;hyphenate:auto;keep-together.within-page:always;font-family:David;font-size:12pt;}

    p.p6{padding-left:90pt;padding-right:82pt;text-align:justify;direction:rtl;hyphenate:none;font-family:David Bold Bold;font-size:12pt;}

    p.p7{text-align:justify;direction:rtl;hyphenate:auto;keep-together.within-page:always;font-family:David;font-size:12pt;}

    p.p8{padding-left:90pt;padding-right:82pt;text-align:justify;hyphenate:none;font-family:David Bold Bold;font-size:12pt;}

    p.p9{text-align:justify;direction:rtl;hyphenate:auto;font-family:David;font-size:12pt;}
    span.s1{font-family:David;}

    span.s2{font-family:David Bold;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}
    span.s3{font-family:David Bold;font-weight:bold;}
    span.s4{font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;}
    span.s5{white-space:pre-wrap;}

    </style>
```

And this is in the Html:

```
<p class"p5">
<span class="s1">"why is the 
<b>bold</b> 
Not Bold???</span>
</p>
```

My problem is that the bold tag is not making the text bold. Why is that?

In Google Chrome it does work but I need this to work in the Android WebView.

Comment: I just put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/XmufZ/ , haven't changed anything, and it works. The only thing jsfiddle doesn't replicate is your font, look for a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use `<b>` tag? You can also use `<strong>`. See if it works. Or alternatively, you could try something like this:

```
<p class"p5">
<span class="s1">"why is the 
<span class="bld">bold</span> 
Not Bold???</span>
</p>
```

and then on your css, add:

> span.bld{font-weight: bold;}

Comment: when i add the class as you offered its working but the editor is putting me <b> tags and i cannot change this. also <strong> is not working

Comment: I have an editor in order to edit the document. and its not in my hands ,this editor for bold making <b> tags and i cannot change it. its working in chrome and so but in the android WebView its Not working.

Comment: why not try enclosing the <b> tag with the <span class="bld"> like <span class="bld"><b>bold</b></span>

Comment: no sorry its not possible solution for my needs . i need to know why the <b> tag is not bold as it is. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap text which has to be bold with the encoded tag. Use `&lt;b&gt;` instead of `<b>` tag.

```
Here is &lt;b&gt; bold text &lt;/b&gt;
```